# Is it okay for a subclass to implement an interface?

Tags: php, oop, strategy-pattern

I am dipping my toes in more serious OOP (previously, just used inheritance) and I have stumbled across something that has confused me.

I have a super class that handles my database connection.

I have a subclass that handles connections related to a site's membership functions

I would like to employ the strategy pattern to allow different but similar functions to coexist. For example:

- connect to database and check name
  and email for new registrations
- connection to database and check username and confirmation code for registration confirmation
- connect to database and check username and password for login

Comment: I hadn't thought about this, i'd be interested to see as well

Comment: your question title is unrelated to your question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can an abstract class extend a super class in PHP?

This

```
class A {}
abstract class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

var_dump( new C );
```

gives

```
object(C)#1 (0) {}
```

so the answer is: Yes, an abstract class can extend a super class in PHP.

**EDIT after title update:**

Yes, it is perfectly fine for a subclass to implement an interface. However, in the context of a Strategy you will likely not call the methods on any other interface than the interface that *captures the abstraction and buries implementation details in derived classes*. See http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code, this is difficult to answer. From what I can derive from your question, I would say in this case you should use composition instead of inheritance.

You could have various "service classes" that incorporate the database connection to make queries relating to a specific problem domain. They all have a property `$dbConnection` they can use to make the queries. You set that property from outside using dependency injection, either with a setter method (`setDbConnection($dbConnection)`) or by passing it in a parameter directly in the constructor of the various service objects.

Comment: within the strategy paradigm I would use interfaces for this, is this not right?

Comment: Ideal thing would be to connect to the database just once for the entire page request. Not sure about the strategy paradigm, but you could add a method setDbConnection to the abstract base class which can be used the instances of the sub classes. Or, you can set the constructor of the abstract class to accept the dbConnection as the parameter.